# ASP.NET MVC with DDD architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

I am trying to understand Asp.Net MVC with DDD following is the structure of application according to the http://aspnetdesignpatterns.codeplex.com/

> Application Layers
>
> Presentation Layer   => MVC views,
>
> Controllers(MVC)     => MVC
>   Controllers class,
>
> Cached Service       => ?,
>
> Application Service  => ?,
>
> Domain Model         => ?,
>
> Repository           => repository
>   class to interact with DB,
>
> Infrastructure       => Class for
>   logging, mailing etc.

here m having confusion in Application service and domain model,
where should i fit my business logic (in service or in domain model)

what exactly should be in service and what should be in domain.

e.g
suppose i want to add customer in DB
how should be the flow..?

as i know,

in controller class i will write like

```
var customeService = new CustomeService (_customerRepository);
customeService.Add(customer);
```

if m wrong please correct me here..

_customerRepository goes in repository

what goes in model and what should be the flow of code.

please clear me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Evan's book is the best place to start DDD as mentioned by @Arnis. [Domain Driven Design Quickly](http://www.loewenbraeuzelt.de/wp-content/uploads/DomainDrivenDesignQuicklyOnline.pdf) is a short, quick-readable summary and introduction to the fundamentals of DDD.

```
what goes in model and what should be the flow of code.
```

Please check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317187/software-architecture-issue/23319648#23319648) from @calebboyd to get an idea of DDD flows.

And about MVC, you can separate the controller from your presentation layers(views). But are you using this controller actions in different projects? If answer is no, my opinion is to keep it in one project.

Answer (score 0):

Have You read [this](http://books.google.lv/books?id=7dlaMs0SECsC&dq=eric+evans+domain+driven+design&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=lv&ei=B01JTL9Q3P6xBvbPsaYP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) book? Start with that.

Term `Service` is [overloaded](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design.aspx).

Domain services encapsulates small part of domain logic that does not fit naturally in any of domain object ([some](http://twitter.com/gregyoung) say it's a sign that there's unidentified aggregate root in Your domain).

Application services contains zero domain logic. They coordinate domain.

Infrastructure services seems to me quite self-explanatory. Those contain technical details.